# CopyDatabaseWizard.exe issue on SQL 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have four servers running Server 2008r2 SP3, of which three were running SQL Server Express 2008r2 and one was running SQL Server Standard 2008r2. After much ado I got these all upgraded to be running SQL Server Standard 2014 SP2.
These servers have .NET 4.6.2 installed and Powershell 2.0 installed.

Unfortunately, now I'm getting this issue in the Application Log on each of these four servers:

```
Event ID 63:
SideBySide (Application Log) 
Activation context generation failed for "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\120\Tools\Binn\managementstudio\CopyDatabaseWizard.exe".
Error in manifest or policy file "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\120\Tools\Binn\managementstudio\CopyDatabaseWizard.exe" on line 8.
The value "1.0" of attribute "version" in element "assemblyIdentity" is invalid.
```

All I can find are some vague technet posts suggesting to use a hex editor to edit the assembly, but that apparently leads to another issue. Editing the exe shouldn't be necessary IMO.

Related technet posts:

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/43ff2fe9-3112-4c0e-ba57-5a2d85a018ab/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-on-an-invocation-during-installation-of-sql-2014-ctp2?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/fa5901bc-a93e-444d-8208-8f2f5584ed94/sidebyside-63?forum=sqlgetstarted
- https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1764660/sidebyside-error

Has anyone run across this or know how to fix this issue? Or is this issue safe to ignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As weird as it is, it currently appears I have resolved this issue by upgrading Powershell. On one server the powershell version was 3.0 and on the other three it was still 2.0.

You can check your powershell version installed by running:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

The upgrade package I used was Windows Management Framework 4.0, which includes Powershell 4.0. PS 4.0 is the last version supported for Server 2008R2. 
Here's a download link to WMF 4.0:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40855

**Edit**

Credit to Antoine Hernandez; Powershell 5.0 *is* supported on Windows Server 2008r2.
Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395

Also quick update after a few days: I haven't had any instances of this issue since I updated Powershell to v4.0.

Comment: Thanks, but 5.0 isn't supported on Server 2008r2

Comment: It is supported on Windows Server 2008 R2. The filename is **Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3134760-x64.msu**.